Запись всех данных, которые выводит цикл в output.txt'
for a in root.select('div.class'):

    quotes = (a.a.get_text(strip=True))
    print(quotes)


with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    print(quotes, file=f)
    f.close()

В чём собственно загвоздка,  в файл сохраняется лишь последняя строчка, хотя в консоль выводится всё содержимое всех классов с одинаковым названиями. 
Как мне записать все данные, которые выводит цикл?

С отступами разберитесь. Сейчас у вас запись идёт после того, как первый цикл закончится. И f.close не нужно с with.

quotes = open("output.txt", "a") если записать так то в конечном итоге не чего не сохранится в данной библиотеке в документации написано что это обязательно проблема в том что он лишь сохранает текст лишь в коце вывода в консоль а не сохраняет весь вывод из консоли в файл

Конечно, не запишется. Потому что в этом коде нет ни одной буквы, которая говорит, что нужно что-то записать в файл.

там и недолжно быть букв причём тут методичка думать надо не шаблонами

Попробуйте так:
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    for a in root.select('div.class'):
        quotes = (a.a.get_text(strip=True))
        print(quotes, file=f)


спасибо работает как то не подумал об этом

@Jacquard пожалуйста
